# Dynamically Finding and Editing a Table Cell using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell

Hi I am having a lot of trouble attempting to figure out how to dynamically know where to rewrite data into a table after the user has made an edit. First I will show you the table code and then where I would like to see my data entered. Thank you for your time!

Table

```
<div id="table">
<br/>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="results_table" width="1140">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>PM Approval</th> <!-- date -->
            <th>Junk Number</th>
            <th>Project Title</th> 
            <th>Project Contact</th>
            <th>Junk</th>
            <th>Verified By</th>
            <th>Date Verified</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($table_data as $row)
    {
        $open = false;
        if(isset($row['Status']) == "Open")
        {
            $open = true;
        }

        if($open)
        {
?>
    <tr class="gradeA">
<?php 
        }
        else
        {
?>
    <tr class="gradeX">
<?php
        }
?>
            <td>
            <!-- popup windows and such --> 
            <button onClick="openPopup(<?php echo $row['ID'];?>);"><?php echo $row['ID'];?></button>
            </td>

            <?php $idt = $row['ID']?>
            <td><?php echo $row['SiteID'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['SiteName'];?></td>
            <td>

                <?php 
                    $db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
                    $db->connect();
                    $getID = $row['SiteTypeID'];
                    $query = "SELECT [Descr] FROM dbo.tblLkpSiteType WHERE dbo.tblLkpSiteType.ID = '$getID'";
                    $db->query($query); 
                    $r = $db->fetch();
                ?>
                <?php                           
                    echo $r['Descr'];
                ?>

            </td>
            <td><?php echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row['UpdatedDate']) );?></td>
            <td><?php 
                  $db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
                  $db->connect();
                  $getID = $row['LTESID'];
                  $query = "SELECT [Descr] FROM dbo.tblLkpLTESType WHERE dbo.tblLkpLTESType.ID = '$getID'";
                  $db->query($query); 
                  $r = $db->fetch();                            
                  echo $r['Descr'];
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php
                    if($row['OperationalAreaID'] != ''){
                      $db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
                      $db->connect();
                      $getID = $row['OperationalAreaID'];
                      $query = "SELECT [Descr] FROM dbo.tblLkpOperationalAreas WHERE dbo.tblLkpOperationalAreas.ID = '$getID'";
                      $db->query($query); 
                      $r = $db->fetch();                            
                      echo $r['Descr']; 
                    }else {echo $row['OperationalAreaID'];}
                 ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            Data Verified
            </td>
            <td>
            Comments
            </td>
            <td>
            C
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

So at this point if the user clicks on an ID number button then how would I use javascript to determine the x and y coordinates of a cell and then update those cells with the respective data?

javascript function

```
<script>
function updateTable()
{
    document.getElementById("testLand").innerHTML = "Post Json";

    //echo new table values in row where ID = button click
}
```

openPopup script

```
<script>
function openPopup(id) {
    document.getElementById('draggable').style.display = 'block';
    if ( true ) console.log( "This element is draggable!" );
    if ( false ) console.log( "This element failed at being draggable!" );
    document.getElementById('popupID').innerHTML = id;
}
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us enough code to help with your specific (where's `openPopup()?`) but here's a general answer. You target the row contextually from the cell that was clicked. This can be inferred from the event object created when the click is made.

Suppose a simple table:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr>
        <td><button>click me</button></td>
        <td>content cell</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

We listen for clicks (only let's do it centrally, from a script, rather than with an inline `onclick` as you currently are):

```
//listen for clicks
document.querySelector('#myTable').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

    //ignore unless it came from a button
    if (evt.target.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;

    //ask user for content - here I use native prompt() but you may have
    //a lightbox dialog script
    var new_content = prompt('Please enter some content', '');

    //update the content cell of the clicked row - we know it's the next
    //child of the clicked cell
    evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML = new_content;

}, false);
```

Comment: I added my open popup script. Can you help me based off that code? Thank you for the time.